# Is there a method to covert an array of 1's and 0's to an array of bytes?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bit

I have a 96-element array of 1's and 0's (I can also use booleans) that I am using to store achievements in a game (0 if not unlocked, 1 if unlocked) that I want to encode as Base64 (to "save" the game by exporting all of the achievement data into a short string). I want to convert the array first into a `byte[]` so that I can use the `encodeToString(byte[] src)` method on that array to output a string.

How can I do this? Is there any method that can take a sub-array of 8 bits and convert it into a byte? This doesn't have to be efficient or pretty. I am just making this game for fun.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use a different data structure, like a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) which will avoid working with bitwise operators directly.

```
BitSet achievements = new BitSet(96);
achievements.set(41);
byte[] data = achievements.toByteArray();
```

Remember: there's no need to reinvent the wheel!

Comment: Beware that if the most significant bits are set to `false`that the resulting array is too small in size; you may have to readjust that (I'd prefer if that code would be in the answer).

Comment: I'm sorry but how can he set the value of the BitSet having only boolean/binary operation? How has to build that value so he can pass it to the set() method? I didn't understand it.

Comment: I mean if the last 2 elements of the array are flagged the value should be 3 (=1+2)? Is there a way to calculate automatically (if it's the correct interpretation)?

Comment: That value 3 will be in the least significant byte if `BitSet#set(1)` and `BitSet#set(0)` is called, right? Is that what you're asking?